# Why does partition parameter of SparkContext.textFile not take effect?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

```
scala> val p=sc.textFile("file:///c:/_home/so-posts.xml", 8) //i've 8 cores
p: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[56] at textFile at <console>:21

scala> p.partitions.size
res33: Int = 729
```

I was expecting 8 to be printed and I see 729 tasks in Spark UI

**EDIT:**

After calling `repartition()` as suggested by @zero323

```
scala> p1 = p.repartition(8)
scala> p1.partitions.size
res60: Int = 8
scala> p1.count
```

I still see 729 tasks in the Spark UI even though the spark-shell prints 8.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you take a look at the signature

```
textFile(path: String, minPartitions: Int = defaultMinPartitions): RDD[String]
```

you'll see that the argument you use is called `minPartitions` and this pretty much describes its function. In some cases even that is ignored but it is a different matter. Input format which is used behind the scenes still decides how to compute splits.

In this particular case you could probably use `mapred.min.split.size` to increase split size (this will work during load) or simply `repartition` after loading (this will take effect after data is loaded) but in general there should be no need for that.

Comment: Please see my edit.calling repartition() had no effect when the job is submitted

Comment: `repartition` will take place after data is loaded. It doesn't modify behavior of `textFile`.

Answer (score 10):

@zero323 nailed it, but I thought I'd add a bit more (low-level) background on how this `minPartitions` input parameter influences the number of partitions.

**tl;dr** The partition parameter does have an effect on `SparkContext.textFile` as the *minimum* (not the exact!) number of partitions.

In this particular case of using [SparkContext.textFile](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L834), the number of partitions are calculated directly by [org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getSplits(jobConf, minPartitions)](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.html#getSplits(org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf,%20int)) that is used by `textFile`. `TextInputFormat` *only* knows how to partition (aka *split*) the distributed data with Spark only following the advice.

From Hadoop's [FileInputFormat's javadoc](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.html):

> FileInputFormat is the base class for all file-based InputFormats. This provides a generic implementation of getSplits(JobConf, int). Subclasses of FileInputFormat can also override the isSplitable(FileSystem, Path) method to ensure input-files are not split-up and are processed as a whole by Mappers.

It is a very good example how Spark leverages Hadoop API.

BTW, You may find [the sources](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.java#L319) enlightening ;-)