# How to set number of splits and reducers in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, emr

I'm trying to run pyspark on amazon EMR instances to read data from dynamodb and would like to know how to set the number of splits and workers in my code?

I followed the instructions from the following two documentations to come with the code below which currently connects to a dynamoDB and reads the data.
[connecting to dynamoDB from pyspark](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyze-your-data-on-amazon-dynamodb-with-apache-spark/)
and [Pyspark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.html)

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
conf = {"dynamodb.servicename": "dynamodb", "dynamodb.input.tableName":
       "Table1", "dynamodb.endpoint": "https://dynamodb.us-east-
        1.amazonaws.com", "dynamodb.regionid":"us-east-1", 
       "mapred.input.format.class": 
       "org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat",
       "mapred.output.format.class": 
       "org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.write.DynamoDBOutputFormat"
orders = sc.hadoopRDD(inputFormatClass="org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat",
                     keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.Text",
                      valueClass="org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBItemWritable", conf=conf)
```

I was trying to change the values of instances and parallelism of SparkConf class but not sure how that will affect the SparkContext variable

```
SparkConf().set('spark.executor.instances','4')
SparkConf().set('spark.default.parallelism', '128')
```

to set the splits and reducers, but it doesn't seem to change it.

Comment: were you able to get its answer? like how to automatically detect things?

Answer (score 3):

> I was trying to change the values of instances and parallelism of SparkConf class but not sure how that will affect the SparkContext variable

Unless `SparkConf` object has been passed during initalization of `SparkContext`

```
conf = SparkConf()  \
    .set('spark.executor.instances','4') \
    .set('spark.default.parallelism', '128')

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

they won't have configuration. If existing context is fetched with `getOrCreate`:

```
sc = SparkContext()
...
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)
```

only some (not `default.parallelism`) will be applied.

> would like to know how to set the number of splits

For RDD inputs use Hadoop configuration (`mapred.min.split.size`):, [Number of Partitions of Spark Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39368516/8371915) and [Why does partition parameter of SparkContext.textFile not take effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34467573/8371915)

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually change the SparkConf is this:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf

sconf = SparkConf()

sconf.set("spark.default.parallelism", 200)

sc = SparkContext(conf = sconf)
```