# Spark: Minimize task/partition size skew with textFile's minPartitions option?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I'm reading in tens of thousands of files into an rdd via something like `sc.textFile("/data/*/*/*")`  One problem is that most of these files are tiny, whereas others are huge.  That leads to imbalanced tasks, which causes all sorts of well-known problems.

Can I break up the largest partitions by instead reading in my data via `sc.textFile("/data/*/*/*", minPartitions=n_files*5)`, where `n_files` is the number of input files?

As convered [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34472018) on stackoverflow, `minPartitions` gets passed way down the hadoop rabit hole and is used in the `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getSplits`.  My question is whether this is implemented such that the largest files are split first.  In other words, is the splitting strategy one that tries to lead to evenly sized partitions?

I would prefer an answer that points to wherever the splitting strategy is actually implemented in a recent version of spark/hadoop.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody's posted an answer so I dug into this myself and will post an answer to my own question:

It appears that, **if your input file(s) are splittable, then `textFile` will indeed try to balance partition size if you use the minPartitions option**.

The partitioning strategy is implemented [here](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.java#L319), i.e., in the `getSplits` method of `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat`.  This partitioning strategy is complex, and operates by first setting `goalSize`, which is simply the total size of the input divided by the `numSplits` (`minPartitions` is passed down to set the value of `numSplits`).  It then splits up files in such a way that tries to ensure that each partition's size (in terms of its input's byte size) is as close as possible to the goalSize/

If your input file(s) are not splittable, then this splitting will not take place: see the source code [here](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.java#L352).